# Wrong records are being deleted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have a table which stores the categories of a list of items(e.g Clothes,Electronics, etc).i wrote a form which lists all the categories in the database and gives the user the option to delete them as he wishes.

**Problem:**

When i try to delete the first record shown, the last record displayed gets deleted instead of the first.The problem does not occur when i try deleting the other records displayed(e.g 2nd,3rd,4th, etc)

**Example:**

```
+---------------------+
|        Category     |
-----------------------
| Clothes  |  Delete  | <---Tried to delete this
-----------------------
| Computers|  Delete  |
-----------------------
| Games    |  Delete  | <--This gets deleted
-----------------------
```

My Form/Processing Code:

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

if($_SESSION['auth']!=="yes")
{
    echo"You are not authorised to view this page. Please login <a href='login.php'>here</a>";
    exit();
}

?>

<?php

if($_POST['delcatsubmit']=="Delete")
{
    include("cxn.inc");
    var_dump($_POST);
    $id=$_SESSION['BizID'];
    $catid=$_POST['delcatid'];
    $delcat=$cxn->prepare("DELETE FROM `testdb`.`itemcat` WHERE `BusinessID`=:id  AND `ID`=:catid");
    $delcat->bindValue(":id",$id);
    $delcat->bindValue(":catid",$catid);
    $delcat->execute();
    echo"Category Deleted";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include("cxn.inc");
    $id=$_SESSION['BizID'];
    $viewcat=$cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `testdb`.`itemcat` WHERE `BusinessID`= :id");
    $viewcat->bindValue(":id",$id);
    $viewcat->execute();
    echo'<form name="delcategory" id="delcategory" action="delcategory.php" method="POST" >';
        echo"<table border='1'>";
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td colspan='2'>";
        echo"Category";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    while($getcat=$viewcat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        $cat=$getcat['ItemCat'];
        $delcatid=$getcat['ID'];
        echo"$cat";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='delcatid' id='delcatid' value='$delcatid' />";
        echo"<input type='submit' name='delcatsubmit' id='delcatsubmit' value='Delete' />";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";

    }
    echo"</form>";
    echo"</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Results of VAR_DUMP($_POST)

```
array(2) { ["delcatid"]=> string(1) "3" ["delcatsubmit"]=> string(6) "Delete" } Category Deleted
```

Questions:

1.Why is the id of the last item displayed being deleted/returned when i try to delete the first item?

2.I get the message:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: delcatsubmit

when i delete a category.I gether that this is due to $_POST['delcatsubmit'] being undefined the first time the form is loaded.Is there any way to correct/remove the notice short of suppressing it with @ ?

I appreciate any inputs and suggestions

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using MYSQL and UNIFORM SERVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

i was using the same name attribute on every row in the form, so they are being overridden and it's using the last one.

What i did to solve it was wrap a new form around every iteration of the submit button as it was being looped.Hope this helps anyone else who encounters the same problem.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include("cxn.inc");
    $id=$_SESSION['BizID'];
    $viewcat=$cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `testdb`.`itemcat` WHERE `BusinessID`= :id");
    $viewcat->bindValue(":id",$id);
    $viewcat->execute();

        echo"<table border='1'>";
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td colspan='2'>";
        echo"Category";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    while($getcat=$viewcat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>";
        $cat=$getcat['ItemCat'];
        $delcatid=$getcat['ID'];
        echo"$cat";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo"$delcatid";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"<td>";
        echo'<form name="delcategory" id="delcategory" action="delcategory.php" method="POST" >';
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='delcatid' id='delcatid' value='$delcatid' />";
        echo"<input type='submit' name='delcatsubmit' id='delcatsubmit' value='Delete' />";
        echo"</form>";
        echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";

    }

    echo"</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```